# Check if parent has text outside of its children

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an XML similar to this one:

```
<parent>
    <child>child's text</child>
    <child>other child's text</child>
    parent's text
</parent>
```

Note that it's allowed to have multiple child elements.

I'd like to know if the parent element has text outside of its children.

I've come up with this solution:

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(parent/child[1]) = normalize-space(parent)">
    <xsl:text>No parent text</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

I use `parent/child[1]` because the normalize-space function doesn't accept a sequence as it's argument.

Is there a better way to do this?

(I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144674/check-if-there-is-a-node-but-not-text) question on the topic but the answer is incorrect or the question is different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text()` to explicitly refer to text nodes.

The better way to do this is:

```
<xsl:if test="parent/text()[not(parent::child)]">
  <!--This parent element has text nodes-->
</xsl:if>
```

Or else, you could write a separate template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()[parent::parent]">
   <xsl:text>parent element with text nodes!</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: parent/text() returns the concatenation of the parent's text plus all of its children's.

Comment: Sorry, not the concatenation. It returns multiple text nodes containing the node's text and its children's. Therefore it doesn't work with normalize-space in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

This template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="parent/child::text()">
                true
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input XML, returns

```
true
```

when applied at the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
    <child>child's text</child>
    <child>other child's text</child>
</parent>
```

returns

```
false
```